# How many plants or trees should one plant to take carbon dioxide from atmosphere?

Tags: trees, global-warming

I'm interested on computing things. I know that some biologists have done mathematical modelling. Has anyone took any calculations on the following?

How many trees or plants should one plant such that those plants takes more $CO_2$ from atmosphere than human uses in his or her life? Feel free to make reasonable assumptions.